# XAMPP and cURL not working, after uncommenting php.ini

Tags: php, curl, xampp, pear, libcurl

[Someone else with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418262/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp) still didn't get a decent answer/fix for my problem:

**Before you comment or criticize, please make sure you read my proceedures below so as not to repeat what I've seen 100x already in Google and Stack Overflow...**

1. XAMPP (Lite) installed on Windows 7 in `C:\xampplite` (newest version, only one `php.ini` file in `C:\xampplite\php`)
2. XAMPP and PHP scripts run correctly in `http://localhost/`
3. libcurl installed (by XAMPP default) in `C:\xampplite\php\ext\php_curl.dll`
4. `php.ini` edited and saved for removal of `;` at beginning of line `extension=php_curl.dll`
5. `php.ini` default for `extension_dir = "C:\xampplite\php\ext"` correct and left alone
6. Apache service restarted in Windows Services
7. Computer restarted
8. Apache service (manually) restarted again
9. `phpinfo();` still does not display anything with the word "curl" in it
10. Still no success

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure but check this out: http://www.kanersan.com/blog.php?blogId=45

Comment: Could it be something like that in your configuration of XAMPP?

Comment: The error code I'm receiving is as follows: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\quicklinks_old\content\yammer_stats\proxy.php on line 160`. This would indicate to me that I'm receiving the errors. I'll take a look though (I do wish that XAMPP's settings were as easy to change as WAMP's is).

Comment: Yeah, looks like curl is not running. Doesn't XAMPP and XAMPP PHP have visual settings like I'm showing in that link I posted above? Also which XAMPP are you using? windows/linux/osx?

Comment: Yes, `display_errors = On` in php.ini

Comment: Like I said in 1. above, Windows 7 :)

Comment: Oh yeah, so just like I'm showing in my blog, go to PHP -> PHP Extensions (instead of PHP Settings) -> php_curl. Turn it on there :)

Comment: I should also note that although it was an issue then too, I was successfully able to get it to work on my previous computer (oh the pains of changing PCs: cURL). Now I'm on round 2 (maybe eventually I'll get this down to a science).

Comment: In essence, that's what I'm doing (except that I'm manually editing the file rather than using a GUI...which XAMPP doesn't have for those settings as far as I'm aware of).

Comment: Create an answer so I can at least give credit to you in the end ;)

Comment: Okay, I was manually editing the php.ini on WAMP without success as well. That's why I posted. But if, no GUI, then I don't know either. Maybe should switch to WAMP? ;)

Comment: I used it for awhile, but it has slightly fewer features than XAMPP from what I recall (the features that I needed/wanted). XAMPP does have a default localhost/ website that gives you status such as phpinfo(), but it's not really useful for adjusting settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem except for error reporting. Searched all over the internet and all I found was "modify the php.ini file". I modified all the php.ini files but I was still getting the same error. Turns out WAMP has visual settings which I believe overwrite the php.ini. So to turn on curl, you'd left click on XAMPP icon in your start start menu -> PHP -> PHP Settings -> php_curl (make sure it is checked).

Maybe this is your problem.

Hope it helps.

-c0d3

Comment: The only thing I can figure is if there's a problem with XAMPP marking my computer as Production rather than Development, which has different set defaults, but I haven't heard of any wide-spread problems like that.

Comment: Now I'm curious too! I wonder why it is not working! Post something if you find out? :)

Comment: I had to add the following to my PHP code to get things to work: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` Maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem but could not find the solution online.

Every site I saw said to uncomment "extension=php_curl.dll" which didn't fix the problem.

I finally solved it by adding the path to curl.dll to the variable.

That is, I changed: extension=php_curl.dll
to:
extension="F:/WebServer/PHP/ext/php_curl.dll"

Hope this helps you or somebody else.

Comment: Bit late but maybe someone else may require this,  you may not have  had `extension_dir = "ext"` uncommented so php knows where the extensions are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing curl

```
xampp/apache/bin/curl.exe
```

with admin privileges.

Comment: What does this help? "C:\xampp\apache\bin>curl.exe", outputs
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Answer (score -3):

Restarting the PHP server will do.