# cURL enabled but not working and not showing in phpinfo()

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I have gone through multiple solutions in StackOverflow but none solved my issue.

I upgraded my XAMPP PHP from 5.6 to 7.2, ever since I am unable to use cURL functionality.
How can I resolve this?

I use this to check in php

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded("curl")) {
  // cURL is loaded...
    echo "CURL Enabled";
} else {
  // cURL is not loaded...
    echo "Chineke...hauna CURL";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extensions may be loaded but not executing (OS issue).

```
if(function_exists('curl_init') === false){
    //curl_init is not defined
    //cURL not enabled
}

<?php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, curl is not part of the loaded extensions, I have already uncommented it in php.ini file @Jin Thakur

Comment: The one found here C:\xampp\php @YvesLeBorg

Comment: @Abiudeko well , i know squat about windows , but on mac and debian and Ubuntu there are multiple php.ini files, depending on the runtime environment (shell, web server, cgi with fpm).  Make certain that you change all three, should wamp-a-dee-doo be a perfect port of other platforms's php.

Comment: Okay, thought you had an idea, thanks for the try anyways @YvesLeBorg

Comment: Looks like you are on windows and you are running it  on IIS. Reset IIS.and try again.

Comment: @JinThakur i thought he said XAMPP ... is the "A" not Apache ... just sayin

Comment: @YvesLeBorg My bad. Just saw  the path. I run on IIS as We have  asp.net apps too. and want to use 80 port only

Comment: Since you're using XAMPP, uncomment the line

;extension=php_curl.dll
in xampp\apache\bin\php.ini, and then restart the Apache service.

NB: In newer XAMP

Comment: php.ini is not available in your mentioned directory @JinThakur

Comment: @Abiudeko For Windows, you can find the file in the C:\xampp\php\php.ini-Folder (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder)

Comment: I think I said I already did that, and it's already established I am using Windows...@JinThakur

Comment: @Abiudeko check if this one works   left click on XAMPP icon in your start start menu -> PHP -> PHP Settings -> php_curl (make sure it is checked).

Comment: @JinThakur I think you deliberately misleading me, even without flipping a finger I am certain there is no such a way to access your method. Please be mindful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775259/xampp-and-curl-not-working-after-uncommenting-php-ini see this marked answer.

Comment: @Abiudeko post your php.ini

Comment: You don't check or uncheck php_curl, you remove the semi-colon before it, which I have mentioned a thousand times I already did that. Do you have any idea on how xampp works? @JinThakur

Comment: @Abiudeko It is you who is asking question and cant get it work.I have everything working for years.

Comment: Then please assist instead of giving instructions that are not applicable to any of the known xampp versions. Kindly recognize the absurd error you made in your answer and at least edit it to reach the threshold, as itt is so not applicable anywhere. @JinThakur

Comment: @Abiudeko  sorry I don't have any solutions for you. I did not make absurd error see my answer after that. It was marked answer. I cannot edit answer because i think it was right answer  at one point for some version of XAMPP. If it is not applicable to you doesn't mean it will be applicable for nobody. 
stackoverflow.com/questions/9775259/… see this marked answer. Post on XAMPP community.